# SQLColumns: Date column is displayed as a varchar column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc

I want know data type for columns in my table. For this I called ODBC function [SQLColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711683(v=vs.85).aspx/). But for each column which has type "date" this function says that column is varchar, but it is not so. Information about data type I know through the field "DATA_TYPE" which return int code of type -9, but this code must be 91. What's the problem, please tell me.

P.S. I use for retrieving information about columns standard C++ code example which is on official page.
P.P.S  For other DBMS this function SQLColumns() works correctly

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess its dependent on the ODBC driver you are using. If it does not support (or request) 2008 or later TDS version, then the type DATE will correctly be returned as VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a query to get the table column info:

```
SELECT tbl.name AS tblName,
    col.name AS fldName,
    typ.name AS Type,
    col.length AS length,
    col.isnullable AS isnullable,
    cmt.text AS DefaultVal
FROM sys.sysobjects tbl
INNER JOIN sys.syscolumns col
    ON col.id = tbl.id
INNER JOIN sys.systypes typ
    ON typ.xtype = col.xtype
LEFT JOIN sys.sysobjects cnst
    ON cnst.xtype = 'D'
    AND cnst.parent_obj = tbl.id
    AND col.cdefault = cnst.id
LEFT JOIN sys.syscomments cmt
    ON cmt.id = cnst.id
WHERE  (tbl.xtype = 'U' OR tbl.xtype = 'V')
    AND (tbl.name <> N'dtproperties') 
    AND (tbl.name <> N'sysconstraints') 
    AND (tbl.name <> N'syssegments') 
    AND (tbl.name = 'MyTestTable')
ORDER BY tbl.name, col.name
```

Output:

```
tblName     fldName     Type    length  isnullable  DefaultVal
MyTestTable action      varchar 10  0   NULL
MyTestTable actionby    varchar 100 0   NULL
MyTestTable actiondate  datetime    8   0   NULL
MyTestTable colname     varchar 50  0   NULL
MyTestTable formfieldname   varchar 100 0   NULL
MyTestTable newvalue    varchar -1  0   NULL
MyTestTable oldvalue    varchar -1  0   NULL
MyTestTable primarykey  varchar 100 0   NULL
MyTestTable sequence    int 4   0   NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But this example is suitable only for the MS SQL. My program can also obtain information about the columns from other DBMS. By the way, for other DBMS this function SQLColumns() works correctly

Comment: you tagged this question as sql-server, but for other rdbs you can do similar sql queries.

Comment: #define SQL_TYPE_DATE      91

Comment: The code is fully similar to code which is presented on page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711683(v=vs.85).aspx/

Section: Code Example

Comment: #define SQL_DATETIME        9

Comment: So is the column a DATE? or a DATETIME?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying. My application implements ODBC 3.0 and ODBC MS SQL driver also corresponds to ODBC 3. 

My column is date, but function returns -9(#define SQL_WVARCHAR -9 from sqlucode.h)

Comment: For example, I use AdventureWorks2008 database. This DB has table HumanResourses.Employee, this table has column BirthDate which is DATE, and if I use SQLColumns for this table, I also get type as WVARCHAR(-9), but this column is DATE

Answer (score 0):

When the type comes back as `WVARCHAR(-9)`, you have to look at the `sqlTypeName` as obtained by

```
SQLCHAR     *sqlTypeName        = NULL;
SQLINTEGER  sqlTypeNameLength   = 0;

sqlTypeName = (unsigned char *)(strSchemaName.GetBuffer(MAX_TEXT_FILE_LINE_LENGTH));

SQLBindCol(m_hSQL,6,SQL_C_CHAR,sqlTypeName,MAX_TEXT_FILE_LINE_LENGTH, &sqlTypeNameLength);
```

It will contain `date`, `time`, or `datetime2`.
Type `WVARCHAR(-9)` is not returned when the data column is a `datetime`.